# xsl: Average of xml elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Could you help me debug in identifying the source of mistake?
I would like to find the average of two elements in xml and add it to the final xml.
I may be doing something fundamentally wrong, could you please help.

Thanks in advance.
fornula
s = (c + d)/2

Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
    <Results>
        <a>no</a>
        <b>12</b>
        <c>12</c>
        <d>9</d>
    </Results>
    <Results>
        <a>yes</a>
        <b>8</b>
        <c>50</c>
        <d>12</d>
    </Results>
    <Results>
        <a>no</a>
        <b>6</b>
        <c>55</c>
        <d>56</d>
    </Results>
    <Results>
        <a>yes</a>
        <b>23</b>
        <c>32</c>
        <d>34</d>
    </Results>
</top>
```

xsl file

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="x" select="//c"/>
  <xsl:variable name="y" select="//d"/>

<xsl:template match="b">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <s>
     <xsl:value-of select="($x + $y) div 2"/>
  </s>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expect Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<top>
  <Results>
    <a>no</a>
    <b>12</b>
    <s>10.5</s>
    <c>12</c>
    <d>9</d>
  </Results>
  <Results>
    <a>yes</a>
    <b>8</b>
    <s>31</s>
    <c>50</c>
    <d>12</d>
  </Results>
  <Results>
    <a>no</a>
    <b>6</b>
    <s>55.5</s>
    <c>55</c>
    <d>56</d>
  </Results>
  <Results>
    <a>yes</a>
    <b>23</b>
    <s>33</s>
    <c>32</c>
    <d>34</d>
  </Results>
</top>
```

The above code and input is a sample to emulate the real data set. Hence, I am looking for idenifying the mistake in this code, which is the part of a larger code. 
Any help would be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

You were thinking too complicated.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Results">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      <s><xsl:value-of select="(sum(c) + sum(d)) div 2" /></s>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you insist on child order in your `<Results>` element, use

```
<xsl:template match="Results">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | a | b" />
    <s><xsl:value-of select="(sum(c) + sum(d)) div 2" /></s>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="c | d" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If there only ever can be one `<c>` and `<d>` in one group, this will be enough:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(c + d) div 2" />
```

Comment: I am looking to fix my code as I have a large number of elements and the average value needs to be inserted in a specific place.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. My solution inserts the average at a specific place.

Comment: Your Solution certainly works in the example, but it would be difficult to implement in a situation whne you have about 40 elements in a set (instead of 4 in the above example). Could you suggest a solution that could be scalable. Thanks

Comment: I still don't know what you mean. My solution works with 4 elements and with 40,000. What do you mean by "scalable"?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have discovered a way to fix the reported issue.

regards

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


<xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <xsl:variable name="x" select="../c"/>
  <xsl:variable name="y" select="../d"/>
  <s><xsl:value-of select="($x + $y) div 2"/></s>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: [Your solution](http://www.xmlplayground.com/2bCK27) and [my solution](http://www.xmlplayground.com/N3O7I6) produce the exact same output. Can you explain why you think your approach is better (or mine is worse)?